# embedding layout inside each tab? - (each tab has its own activity)

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have started with the HelloTabwidget example and it works fine. Now what I am trying to do is have a layout inside each tab. here is what the code looks like

```
myApp extends TabActivity {
  TabHost tabHost;
  onCreate() {
      setContentView (R.layout.main);
      tabHost = getTabHost();
      TabHost.tabspec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(..).setIndicator(...).
               setContent(new Intent().setClass(...));
       tabHost.addTab(spec);
       :
  }
}

myTab1Actvity extends Activity {
  ListView myLV;
  EditText myET;

  onCreate() {
    setcontentView (TAB1_LAYOUT);

        myLV = findViewById(..);
  :
     myLV.setAdapter(aa);
     myET.setOnKeyListener(....)
    registerforContextMenu(myLV)
  }
}
```

when I run here is the stack trace

```
 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(691): java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(691):     at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(TabHost.java:295)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(691):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(691):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(691):     at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(TabHost.java:295)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(691):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(691):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(691):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(691):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1819)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(691):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(691):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(691):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(691):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(691):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(691):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(691):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Does the code's flow look OK? basically each Tab has its own activity and each tab has its own layout.

It appears that something is wrong in the TabHost - but I am unable to pinpoint it. Any suggestions/Qs you hav e will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reminds me of the "infinite monkey theorem'  - anyways the problem was the layout files meant for each tab also had a TabHost in them. The first level (root) tag I used is the LinearLayout (and not TabHost)

Comment: yes, I wrap TabHost to a LinearLayout, and this bug is fixed. Thanks very much.

Comment: Sir, i had same problem. But my application is working fine when i run my application on android device. but create above errors when i run this application on emulator. Please suggest me what should i do . Thank you i advance